# image unexpectedly stretched in ImageView on 2.2

Tags: android-imageview

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid in an ImageView extension.  On Android 4.0.3 it looks fine, but on 2.2 it gets stretched on the right and bottom sides, so that my cells on those edges look twice as big.

Here's the grid-creating code:

```
cellheight = Math.round((float) (Math.floor((height - (bordersize * 2) - (linesize * (numrows - 1))) / numrows)));
cellwidth = Math.round((float) (Math.floor((width - (bordersize * 2) - (linesize * (numcols - 1))) / numcols)));
height = bordersize * 2 + (linesize * (numrows - 1)) + cellheight * numrows;
width = bordersize * 2 + (linesize * (numcols - 1)) + cellwidth * numcols;

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
setImageBitmap(bitmap);

canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, cellpaint);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bordersize, height, borderpaint);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, bordersize, borderpaint);
canvas.drawRect(0, height - bordersize, width, height, borderpaint);
canvas.drawRect(width - bordersize, 0, width, height, borderpaint);

for (int i = 1; i < numrows; ++i)
  canvas.drawRect(bordersize, bordersize + (i * cellheight) - (linesize / 2), width - bordersize, 
    bordersize + (i * cellheight) + (linesize / 2), linepaint);

for (int i = 1; i < numcols; ++i)
  canvas.drawRect(bordersize + (i * cellwidth) - (linesize / 2), bordersize, 
    bordersize + (i * cellwidth) + (linesize / 2), height - bordersize, linepaint);
```

For height and width 300, numrows and numcols 8, bordersize 8 and linesize 3, it recalculates height and width to 293 and makes a square grid.  But on 2.2 that grid gets stretched on right and bottom sides, extending the borders and lines, to almost the size of another row/column of cells.

I've tried WRAP_CONTENT on both the ImageView and the wrapping LinearLayout.  I've tried various values for setScaleType().  I've tried setMaxHeight() and setMaxWidth().  Nothing I've tried seems to prevent the stretching on 2.2.

Any ideas?